# Unable to Run Spring Boot project on IDEA after replace Tomcat instead of Jetty

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jetty

I'm the new to IDEA.When I create a Spring Boot project (Hello World..) on IDEA, it's easy to run by default configuration.
But, after replace Tomcat instead of Jetty, it's failure to RUN.
my pom.xml like this:

> ```
>   <parent>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>       <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
>       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
>     </parent>
>     <properties>
>       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
>       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>     </properties>
>     <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>           <exclusions>
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>           </exclusions>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
>     <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>     </build>
> ```

the error message like this:

```
2017-04-21 17:10:50.448  INFO 10132 --- [           main] com.example.JettyDemoApplication         : Starting JettyDemoApplication on HuaTai-PC with PID 10132 (E:\aaa_coding-2017\jetty-demo\target\classes started by HuaTai in E:\aaa_coding-2017\jetty-demo)
2017-04-21 17:10:50.451  INFO 10132 --- [           main] com.example.JettyDemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-21 17:10:50.548  INFO 10132 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@77ec78b9: startup date [Fri Apr 21 17:10:50 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-21 17:10:51.610  WARN 10132 --- [           main] o.h.v.m.ParameterMessageInterpolator     : HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
2017-04-21 17:10:51.858  WARN 10132 --- [           main] o.h.v.m.ParameterMessageInterpolator     : HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
2017-04-21 17:10:52.291  INFO 10132 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-21 17:10:52.305  INFO 10132 --- [           main] com.example.JettyDemoApplication         : Started JettyDemoApplication in 2.241 seconds (JVM running for 2.705)
2017-04-21 17:10:52.306  INFO 10132 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@77ec78b9: startup date [Fri Apr 21 17:10:50 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-21 17:10:52.307  INFO 10132 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

thanks all

Comment: No error message in that output.

Comment: Then why can not I start the application by jetty?

Comment: don't know, as there's no `org.eclipse.jetty` lines present in your logging output.  there's nothing indicating that core jetty components where even initialized or configured or start attempted.  can you set `org.eclipse.jetty` to at least INFO level and try again?

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try again